# WSFederationAuthenticationModule v/s SessionAuthenticationModule

Tags: asp.net, wif

According to documentation, both module will used to create instance of IClaimsPrincipal. I am not understanding why WIF bother to use 2 HttpModules instead of one? Sorry, I am new in WIF

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need both to have the `IClaimsPrincipal` in the pipeline. You need the latter, the `SessionAuthenticationModule`. It is responsible for converting the WIF cookie into the principal object (similar what FormsAuthenticationModule does with a form cookie).

The former, `WSFederationAuthenticationModule` is responsible only for the initial SAML post from the indentity provider to your application - the module consumes the post and issues the WIF cookie. Alternatively you can do it with a `wif:FederatedPassiveSignIn` control placed on your login form.

When I code WIF-enabled applications, I usually have only the SAM module and I use the login control for issuing cookies.

Comment: Is you don't think that one HttpModule is enough for this? FederatedPassiveSignIn is no longer available in 4.5

Comment: Some time ago I've recreated it http://code.google.com/p/net45federatedpassivesignin/

Answer (score 5):

The big difference is that the WSFederationAuthenticationModule intercepts requests and will redirect the user to be authenticated by the STS while the SessionAuthenticationModule uses the WIF-token cookie to authorize the user on subsequent requests.

The SessionAuthenticationModule fires first in the pipeline so if you already have a session cookie (i.e., you've already been authenticated), the session module will grant you access.

The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj191638.aspx) does a decent job of describing this.

Comment: Is you don't think that one HttpModule is enough for this?

Comment: I didn't design it so I can't tell you why the decision was made to split it into two different modules. However, there are distinct purposes for each one, and it allows for more extensibility.