# Federated Authentication on Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, wif

I'm using WIF (.net 4.5), and Azure Active directory for authentication. The website will sit on Azure.

Everything works as expected locally, however when I put it onto azure I get the error:

> The data protection operation was unsuccessful. This may have been caused by not having the user profile loaded for the current thread's user context, which may be the case when the thread is impersonating.

I understand this is because the apps can't use DAPI, so I need to switch to protecting my app with the MAC.

Locally I added this to my webconfig:-

```
 <securityTokenHandlers>
    <remove type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    <add type="System.IdentityModel.Services.Tokens.MachineKeySessionSecurityTokenHandler, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  </securityTokenHandlers>
```

as recommended in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.services.tokens.machinekeysessionsecuritytokenhandler.aspx), and I added a static machine key, but I can't find any advice around the key length - so I have assumed 256.

This configuration however just gives this error:

> [CryptographicException: Error occurred during a cryptographic operation.]
>      System.Web.Security.Cryptography.HomogenizingCryptoServiceWrapper.HomogenizeErrors(Func`2 func, Byte[] input) +115
>      System.Web.Security.Cryptography.HomogenizingCryptoServiceWrapper.Unprotect(Byte[] protectedData) +59
>      System.Web.Security.MachineKey.Unprotect(ICryptoServiceProvider cryptoServiceProvider, Byte[] protectedData, String[] purposes) +62
>      System.Web.Security.MachineKey.Unprotect(Byte[] protectedData, String[] purposes) +122
>      System.IdentityModel.Services.MachineKeyTransform.Decode(Byte[] encoded) +161
>      System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler.ApplyTransforms(Byte[] cookie, Boolean outbound) +123
>      System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler.ReadToken(XmlReader reader, SecurityTokenResolver tokenResolver) +575
>      System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler.ReadToken(Byte[] token, SecurityTokenResolver tokenResolver) +76
>      System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule.ReadSessionTokenFromCookie(Byte[] sessionCookie) +833
>      System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule.TryReadSessionTokenFromCookie(SessionSecurityToken& sessionToken) +186
>      System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule.OnAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs eventArgs) +210
>      System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +136
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +69

I removed the machinekey section incase I hadn't specified a correctly formatted key, but the error doesn't go away.

What a fight WIF has been!

Comment: To fix my problem I added that to the web.config and generated a machine key with this site http://aspnetresources.com/tools/machineKey

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If you don't specify machineKey in configuration, Azure adds one. But if you create new version of your application and deploy it to Azure using VIP switching, Azure generates a new machine Key for the deployment in Staging (assuming your first deployment was to Production). (VIP switching is nice mechanism for deploying new version and then switching virtual IP addresses between Production and Staging).

So basically one solution is letting Azure to generate the key but after VIP switch you have the problem back. To avoid it you can catch the CryptographicException in Global.asax in Application_Error handler, something like this:

```
// Be sure to reference System.IdentityModel.Services
// and include using System.IdentityModel.Services; 
// at the start of your class
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var error = Server.GetLastError();
    var cryptoEx = error as CryptographicException;
    if (cryptoEx != null)
    {
        FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.SignOut();
        Server.ClearError();
    }
}
```

The SignOut() method causes the cookie is removed.

**Edit**: updated info on generating machineKey as noted by @anjdreas.

Another solution is to generate the machineKey, you can use IIS Manager to do it, see [Easiest way to generate MachineKey](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/amb/archive/2012/07/31/easiest-way-to-generate-machinekey.aspx) for details. If you put the same key into all your web appliactions within Azure Web Role, the Azure deployment process will not replace it.

Comment: If you don't want to use a 3rd party site, you can also use IIS Manager to generate the keys for you. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/amb/archive/2012/07/31/easiest-way-to-generate-machinekey.aspx

Comment: aspnetresources.com appears to be a parked domain now.  You should rewrite the last paragraph with anjdreas's link

Comment: The FederatedAuthentication in FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule is saying the name in 'FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule' does not exist in the current context and can't find what using i need to add.

Using .net 4.6

Comment: @JQuery Assembly System.IdentityModel.Services, namespace: System.IdentityModel.Services. See [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.services.wsfederationauthenticationmodule(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks, I can add using System.IdentityModel to the global.asx but when i try adding Services i get

The type or namespace name 'Services' does not exist in the namespace 'System.IdentityModel' (are you missing an assembly reference?) 

Using directive is unnecessary.

Comment: trying this in relation to an error i am getting if possible see - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34650138/error-occurred-during-a-cryptographic-operation-in-debug

Comment: I am using the `SessionAuthenticationModule` rather than `WSFederationAuthenticationModule` for managing cookies, so I had to use
`FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.DeleteSessionTokenCookie()` instead of `SignOut()`. If using both [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13398903/4289902) may be useful...

Answer (score 4):

The machine key shouldn't be there: Windows Azure generates one for you and makes sure it is identical on every instance in your role.

About the error you're seeing: can you try clearing cookies?

Comment: unreal, that sorted it! Thanks!!

Comment: Reason is that you probably tried it first with the regular session manager -> it leaves a cookie that can't be decrypted because you basically changed the mechanism switching to machine key :-)

Comment: Yup, makes sense now I think about it! Thanks for the help.

Comment: They should really clear out the "bad" cookies instead of just complaining that something is wrong ;)

Answer (score 2):

Simply clearing the cookies solved the whole problem for me in this case.

Comment: Clearing the cookies worked for us too but this solution is not optimal as users will still see the error and need instructions for how to clear their cookies. Still, this is a solution so thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using forms auth. you can signout when you catch the exception and allow your users to login and create a valid cookie

```
catch (CryptographicException cex)
{
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
}
```

Comment: We had a problem with the solutions sign the user out automatically. Removing the cookie using this technique doesn't solve the problem and, when the cookies were cleared, the user was repeatedly signed out.

We tried explicitly set the machinekey in the application's web.config file like this:

    <system.web>
    ...
       <machineKey decryption="AES" decryptionKey="our_decript_key" validation="SHA1" validationKey="our_validation key" />
    </system.web>

We generated the encryption key using IIS7. We are still getting the error.

Answer (score -2):

Asking all the users to clear all cookies wasn't really an option for me.  On [this site](http://anuchandy.blogspot.com/2014/06/acs-wif-asp-net-and-microsoft-azure.html#comment-form) and also in the book "Programming Windows Identity Federation" I found a better solution (for me, anyways).  If you're already uploading an SSL certificate to Azure, you can use that certificate to also encrypt your cookie on all Azure instances, and you won't need to worry about new machine keys, IIS user profiles, etc.