# Federated Authentication and "Error occurred during a cryptographic operation"

Tags: asp.net, .net, federated-identity

I got this exception when I try get my home page on ASP.NET MVC application.

> [CryptographicException: Error occurred during a cryptographic
>   operation.]
>   System.Web.Security.Cryptography.HomogenizingCryptoServiceWrapper.HomogenizeErrors(Func`2
>   func, Byte[] input) +246
>   System.IdentityModel.Services.MachineKeyTransform.Decode(Byte[]
>   encoded) +191
>   System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler.ApplyTransforms(Byte[]
>   cookie, Boolean outbound) +173
>   System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler.ReadToken(XmlReader
>   reader, SecurityTokenResolver tokenResolver) +756
>   System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler.ReadToken(Byte[]
>   token, SecurityTokenResolver tokenResolver) +100
>   System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule.ReadSessionTokenFromCookie(Byte[]
>   sessionCookie) +1164
>   System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule.TryReadSessionTokenFromCookie(SessionSecurityToken&
>   sessionToken) +287
>   System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule.OnAuthenticateRequest(Object
>   sender, EventArgs eventArgs) +231
>   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +80    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +165

From what I understand something get wrong in the cookie for SessionAuthenticationModule. If you clear the cookies (as stated already here [Federated Authentication on Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119965/federated-authentication-on-azure)) it works. What I would like is to understand what is going on, how to catche the exceptions and fix the issue.

Comment: How do you issue cookies?

Comment: Is your app on Azure?

Comment: @WiktorZychla: They were from a previous build and cached in my browser

Comment: @SimonHalsey: Yes they will be but for now they are run locally with the compute emulator, iis express, ...

Comment: Sounds like a duplicate of this then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119965/federated-authentication-on-azure

Comment: @WiktorZychla: Same problem I guess but wrong solution. We can't ask everyone to clean there cache when we see this error. What I would like is to understand what is going on, how to catche the exceptions and fix the issue.

Comment: Thr easiest workaround would be to change the name of the cookie in your cookie section of federation settings. This way old cookies would be discarded at the server side.

Answer (score 17):

The cookie, when issued, contains security token encrypted using the current machineKey. When the cookie from the previous build is sent back to server, SAM (more precisely the token handler) tries to decrypt it using the new value of machineKey which causes the error.
Check my answer in the related post ([Federated Authentication on Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119965/federated-authentication-on-azure)) to mitigate the error. HTH

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same problem. 
I just cleared all of **browser's cookies** and **cache data** and it got fixed.

Comment: In my case, It is fine since i fixed it.

Comment: Well, how did you fix it?

Comment: I was logged in with old credentials, i made some chages in my authentication and that exception occured. Then I washed-out all of my browser's cache and cookies and I logged out and logged in, problem solved.

Comment: It is a quick fix, for make a solution work. This is not a full fix to the issue.

Comment: what is the full fix then ? @Juan Acosta

Comment: @BaqerNaqvi so you are manually clearing the cookies each time you experience this problem? Great fix,....