# How to handle CryptographicException after long inactivity in ASP .NET MVC with Azure AD credentials?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, active-directory

I'm using Azure Active Directory application which contains user data and credentials. I access ASP .NET MVC 5 application with this credentials using Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient library. After long inactivity, about 20 minutes, and clicking some link I got plain Server Runtime Error and cannot refresh page and login again. Only clearing cookies works.

What I tried:

- handle this error with customErrors - doesn't seem to work
- catching it in:

`protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var error = Server.GetLastError();
            var cryptoEx = error as CryptographicException;
            if (cryptoEx != null)
            {
                FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.SignOut();
                Server.ClearError();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/");
            } 
        }`

as described here: [Federated Authentication on Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119965/federated-authentication-on-azure)

- problem does not exist while I'm using debugger and local machine, only on production - does it depend on IIS config?
- may I change sessionTimeout of Azure AD cookies not to wait 20 minutes every time?
- should I use 'static' machine key - not generated every time by Azure AD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally made a workaround: instead of handling this nasty exception I'm just keeping the session up with javascript scheduled requests which are invoking controller and setting some `Session["Value"]`

Answer (score 0):

I also handled this by making sure my pages refresh every 30 minutes.

This can be done in HTML by adding the meta tag

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1800">
```

It can also be done via Javascript

```
setInterval(function() {
              window.location.reload();
            }, 180000);
```